# Secure transfer of password from iPhone app to web server

Tags: php, iphone, ios5, nsurlrequest

This is probably asked somewhere else, but I sure can't find it...

I am building an iPhone app that will take the username and password from UITextFields and use them to login.

My php script takes a $_REQUEST["user"] and $_REQUEST["password"] to login. I got this working:

```
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender {
    NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://localhost:8443/index.php?at=main&pre=login&pre=login&user=%@&password=%@", _usernameentered, _passwordentered];
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
};
```

However, the password is still sent in plain text. I need to send it as a POST variable, but I am not sure how to do that. I feel like there should be a couple lines of code to tell what the POST variables are, but I can't really find anything on the internet. Maybe I am searching with the wrong terms.

Also, I am developing for ios5, so I don't want to us ASIHTTPrequest.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "password is still sent in plain text" nothing sent via http*s* is plain text

Comment: True...I was more meaning that it ends up in the url when the page has loaded

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Here is a [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html).  It is good that you are using HTTPS.

Comment: How do you use that to append a POST variable. I played around with NSURLConnection as well, and got it working, but wasn't sure where to go from there.

Comment: use NSMutableURLRequest. check out this example: http://deusty.blogspot.com/2006/11/sending-http-get-and-post-from-cocoa.html